# Hamiltonian Quaternions: A Call for Counterexample for ($AB=I_m \implies n≥m$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, modules

How can I build a counterexample to $AB=I_m \implies n≥m$ in the ring of Hamiltonian quaternions? Notice that the vectors $(1,i)$ and $(j,k)=(1,i)j$ are linearly dependent as vectors of the right $\mathbb{H}$-module $\mathbb{H}^2$, but they are linearly independent as vectors of the left $\mathbb{H}$-module $\mathbb{H}^2$

---

Acknowledgement: Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: I think you forgot to say something.  Here's my _guess_ about what it is: $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix.  Somehow you've got to say what $n$ is if your question is to make sense.

Comment: I did not have this specific question mind, when I suggested that construction. It was just a generic remark on how some facts about linear algebra go out of the window, when we exit the commutative realm :-)  Let's see...

Comment: Multiplying a column vector in $\mathbb{H}^m$ from the left by the matrix $B$ will be a morphism of right $\mathbb{H}$-modules. Hmm. Doesn't look good :-(

Comment: I have a vague recollection of somebody (Arturo Magidin?) having written an answer listing general facts about different types of ranks of matrices over a skewfield, but I can't locate it now. IIRC you need to define quantities like left/right column/row rank, and work with those.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with entries from $\Bbb H$, and $AB=I_m$, this is saying that $A$ provides a surjective right $\Bbb H$ linear transformation from $\Bbb H^n\to\Bbb H^m$.

By the rank-nullity theorem (it still holds for division rings), $m\leq n$.

Comment: I guess I am misunderstanding the question. This interpretation seems like the most likely, but it seems pretty clear there will be no counterexamples.

Comment: +1 Yes. I did not think it through or phrase the suggestion carefully enough.